# Как реализовать mysql запрос?

Tags: mysql, node.js

на мой бэкенд приходит Object с полями

```
const info = {
id: 27,
name: Michael,
surname: Jackson,
email: email@gmail.com,
password: 123456789,
avatar: ''
}
```

если пользователь не ввел на пример `name` то она придет просто пустой.
мне нужно изменить в БД те поля который не пустые.
если бы всегда приходили все поля с значениями то мой код выглядел бы так

```
`UPDATE users SET name=${info.name},surname=${info.surname},email=${info.email},password=${info.password},avatar=${info.avatar} WHERE id=${info.id}`
```

изза того что иногда приходят поля с пустыми значениями mysql ругается на пустые поля по этому нужно реализовать изменения тех таблиц у которых есть новые значения

Comment: Пустое поле - это `''`, `null` или отсутствие поля в объекте?

Comment: не `null` а просто пустая строка `''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете вручную сформировать sql-запрос

```js
const info = {
  id: 27,
  name: 'Michael',
  surname: 'Jackson',
  email: 'email @gmail.com',
  password: '123456789',
  avatar: ''
};

const { id, ...userData } = info;

const sqlParts = Object.keys(userData).reduce(
  (acc, key) => {
    const val = userData[key];
    if (val !== undefined && val !== '') {
      acc.push(`${key}="${val}"`);
    }
    return acc;
  },
  []
);

const sql = `UPDATE users SET ${sqlParts.join(', ')} where id = ${id}`;

console.log(sql);
```

Но так лучше не делать. Воспользуйтесь готовыми orm или query builder-ом:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/knex

Comment: Спасибо за помощь !!!

Comment: пожалуйста, пометьте ответ принятым, если он вам помог